# Computing limit with Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to compute the following limit:
$$
  \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{n-2}}{1+x^n} \cos(\pi n x) \,dx .
$$
This is a problem in an old analysis qualifying exam.

Let $f_n(x) = \frac{x^{n-2}}{1+x^n} \cos(\pi n x)$.
Since
$$
  \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)
= \begin{cases}
0 & x \neq 1 \\
1/2 & x=1 ,
\end{cases} 
$$
if I could show that $|f_n| \leq g$ for some $g \in L^1$, then the Dominated Convergence Theorem would imply that the limit in question is zero.

I'm having trouble finding such a $g$ and have started doubting my approach. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Try considering $\int_0^1$ and $\int_1^\infty$ separately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The $-2$ in the exponent of the nominator *screams* "Use $\frac{1}{x^2}$, use $\frac{1}{x^2}$!".

And indeed, for $x \geq 1$, $$
  \frac{x^{n-2}}{1 + x^n} = \frac{1}{x^{2-n} + x^2} \leq \frac{1}{x^2} \text{.}
$$

For $0 \leq x \leq 1$, we just need that the integrand ins bounded, and bounded it is because  $$
  \frac{x^{n-2}}{1 + x^n} \leq \frac{1}{1+ x^n} \leq \frac{1}{2} \text{.}
$$

Out of pur vanity we double that bound because discontinuity just isn't *pretty*, and use $$
  g(x) = \begin{cases}
    1 &\text{if $x \leq 1$} \\
  \tfrac{1}{x^2} &\text{if $x > 1$.}
  \end{cases}
$$

Comment: Very nice answer! +1